# In the command column of htop, sometimes the full path is displayed, and sometimes it isn't. Why?

Tags: htop

[image: A screenshot of htop running in a terminal emulator.]

Above is htop running in a terminal emulator. In the command column, some of the processes have their full path, eg. /usr/bin/python3, and some of them have just the command name, eg. caja, xonsh.

Why is there a difference? Is there anything special about these processes?

I suspect, but I'm not sure, that this might be the first element of "args" (unclear what the true name of it is), the program name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page of htop:

```
Command
        The full command line of the process (i.e. program name and arguments).
```

So if you run `htop` you will see the command without the full path. And if you run `/usr/bin/htop -C -u$USER` you will see the full path with arguments.

Answer (score 4):

While htop is running, you can toggle full path display with `p` shortkey

Comment: `p` stopped doing anything for me with more recent versions of `htop`. Wonder if that's a bug.